# Passing query parameters to a C# CGI program in Apache on Windows

Tags: c#, apache, cgi, query-string

I'm running a C# program as a CGI script in Apache on Windows, which works just fine.  However, I'm now trying to pass it query parameters, e.g.

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/csharp_program.exe?hello=kitty&goodbye=world
```

I understand that my query parameters will be passed in the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable, e.g.

```
`hello=kitty&goodbye=world`
```

What functions/classes in C# exist to parse these query parameters for me so that I don't need to reinvent the wheel and do it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [System.Web.HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httprequest.aspx).  In .NET 3.5 it has a public constructor that takes a file, URL, and query string.  I've never used it in a CGI process, but you could probably fake the file and URL.  Then you can access the QueryString property which is a NameValueCollection.

You could also go the reflection route and create an instance of HttpValueCollection (internal to System.Web) which is a NameValueCollection.